# Command Dispatcher using Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, decorator, cqrs

I'm implementing an MVC application using the command decorator pattern with Unity as IoC.

**Problem**: My concern now is I've some controllers which are injected with multiple command handler interface types.  The samples I've found so far are for [Ninject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610154/ImplementingplusaplusCQRS-basedplusArchitectureplu) and Autofac.

**Objective**: I'm looking to implement a command dispatcher that will smartly decide which command handler to resolve based on the command so that I won't have to deal with managing the constructor of my controllers.

I've my command handler interface.

```
public interface ICommandHandlerAsync<TCommand> 
{
    Task Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

My controller has the following constructor

```
public MemberRegistrationController(
        Func<ICommandHandlerAsync<RegisterMemberCommand>> registerMemberCommandHanderFactory,
        Func<ICommandHandlerAsync<UnregisterMemberCommand>> unregisterMemberCommandHanderFactory)
{
...
}

public async void Register(RegisterMemberViewModel vm)
{
    // Map to command using extension
    var cmd = vm.MapToCommand();

    // Run command
    await registerMemberCommandHanderFactory().Handle(cmd);
}

public async void Unregister(UnregisterMemberViewModel vm)
{
    // Map to command using extension
    var cmd = vm.MapToCommand();

    // Run command
    await unregisterMemberCommandHanderFactory().Handle(cmd);
}
```

What I'd want is something like
public MemberRegistrationController(
            Func commandDispatcherFactory
    {
    ...
    }

```
public async void Register(RegisterMemberViewModel vm)
{
    // Map to command using extension
    var cmd = vm.MapToCommand();

    // Run command
    await commandDispatcherFactory().Dispatch(cmd);
}

public async void Unregister(UnregisterMemberViewModel vm)
{
    // Map to command using extension
    var cmd = vm.MapToCommand();

    // Run command
    await commandDispatcherFactory().Dispatch(cmd);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a command handler factory, which uses Unity to get a new instance of the appropriated `ICommandHandlerAsync<TCommand>` (The [default lifetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx#Anchor_0) in Unity is transient, which means you will get a new instance every time you resolve a type):

```
public interface ICommandHandlerFactory
{
    ICommandHandlerAsync<TCommand> GetHandlerFor<TCommand>(TCommand command);
}

public class CommandHandlerFactory: ICommandHandlerFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer container;
    public CommandHandlerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public ICommandHandlerAsync<TCommand> GetHandlerFor<TCommand>(TCommand command)
    {
        return this.container.Resolve<ICommandHandlerAsync<TCommand>>();
    }
}
```

You can then register the factory and the command handlers in Unity:

```
var container = new UnityContainer()
        .RegisterType<ICommandHandlerAsync<RegisterMemberCommand>, RegisterMemberCommandHandler>()
        .RegisterType<ICommandHandlerAsync<UnregisterMemberCommand>, UnregisterMemberCommandHandler>()
        .RegisterType<ICommandHandlerFactory, CommandHandlerFactory>();
```

Your controller will receive the factory in its constructor. The action methods will use the factory to dispatch the commands:

```
public MemberRegistrationController(ICommandHandlerFactory commandHandlerFactory)
{
    this.commandHandlerFactory = commandHandlerFactory;
}

public async void Register(RegisterMemberViewModel vm)
{
    // Map to command using extension
    var cmd = vm.MapToCommand();

    // Run command
    await commandHandlerFactory.GetHandlerFor(cmd).Handle(cmd);
}

public async void Unregister(UnregisterMemberViewModel vm)
{
    // Map to command using extension
    var cmd = vm.MapToCommand();

    // Run command
    await commandHandlerFactory.GetHandlerFor(cmd).Handle(cmd);
}
```

I have set a demo in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZfSVgc).

Comment: You're right, so simple after all :)  I did write a factory as a resolver for something else but didn't cross my mind I can do the same here.  Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: I've been trying to scan my assemblies and dynamically register all classes that implement ICommandHandlerAsync<TCommand> . So far I havent had much luck, anyone have a link to an example? Or know if this is possible?